# ASP.NET MVC does not have the matching return type

Tags: c#

I have the following code in my repository:

```
public PerformanceDetails performanceDetails(String name, String year)
{
    var PerformanceDetails = (from s in _db.PerformanceDetails where s.venue == name && s.year == year select s).First();

    return PerformanceDetails;
}
```

and then this is the interface:

```
Performance performanceDetails(String name, String year);
```

In the controller I have the following ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Details(String name, String year)
{
    return View(_repository.performanceDetails(name, year));
}
```

As far as I can tell this should be fine but when I try and build the solution it gives an error saying:

> Error 1   'u0558234_assignment2.Models.StageRepository' does not implement interface member 'u0558234_assignment2.Models.IStageRepository.performanceDetails(string, string)'. 'u0558234_assignment2.Models.StageRepository.performanceDetails(string, string)' cannot implement 'u0558234_assignment2.Models.IStageRepository.performanceDetails(string, string)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'u0558234_assignment2.Models.Performance'.    C:\Users\cameron\Desktop\u0558234_assignment2\u0558234_assignment2\Models\StageRepository.cs    8   18  u0558234_assignment2

Any ideas what the problem is? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of `performanceDetails` is returning `PerformanceDetails` not `Performance`

Comment: Damn! Yeah just seen it in the interface. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your method must return `Performance` as declared in the interface and not `PerformanceDetails`. If you want to return details you will need to modify the interface you are implementing to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

The return type in the interface is `Performance`, but the method has the return type `PerformanceDetails`.